# Mathematica doesn't solve Friedmann's equation, how to proceed?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I'm working on a especific cosmological setting that culminates in the following equation: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YESWs.jpg). But when I try to solve it through the DSolve method in Mathematica I get the input as a result.
The code written was exactly this:

```
eqn = a[t] a'[t]^2 - B*a[t]^3 == C + D*Cos[\[Omega]*t + \[Phi]]
DSolve[eqn, a[t], t]
```

and the output is:  `DSolve[-B a[t]^3 + a[t] Derivative[1][a][t]^2 ==  C + D Cos[\[Phi] + t \[Omega]], a[t], t]`. B, C and D are constants and the equation was written in this form so it looks cleaner. I want the software to give me a general solution for a[t] and I am looking for a way to do it.

It's suposed to have a closed-form solution, but there's a slight chance that it doesn't because of the chosen trigonometric parametrization. All of the constants are non-zero. And is not possible to give typical values for the constants, because they depend on a free parameter.

Comment: Are you sure there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: If you set D=0, you can get a collection of answers for a[t]

Comment: You will also get results for omega = 0

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of a harmonic steady state solution   $a(t)\approx \text{cc}+\text{dd} \cos (t \omega
   )+\text{ee} \sin (t \omega )$ ? If yes, please provide some examplary values for the parameters. Perturbation theorie might provide  a solution.

Comment: It's suposed to have a closed-form solution, but there's a slight chance that it doesn't because of the chosen trigonometric parametrization. All of the constants are non-zero. And is not possible to give typical values for the constants, because they depend on a free parameter.

Comment: I am surprised that nobody mentioned it, but it's a bad idea to use certain capital letters as they are built-in symbols. Those are the following `O`,`N`,`E`,`D`,`I`,`C`,`K`

Comment: **Maple 2022.2** also can't solve. If you want a **Series** solution: `AsymptoticDSolveValue[
 a[t]*a'[t]^2 - b*a[t]^3 == c + d*Cos[\[Omega]*t + \[Phi]], 
 a[t], {t, 0, 3}]` ?